# Error while working with PayPal in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am getting following error while integrating PayPal in WooCommerce/WordPress.

```
Error: The API credentials you provided are not valid. Please double-check that you entered them correctly and try again.
```

I have supplied proper credentials from the Sandbox.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The error itself says that The API credentials you provided are not valid.

Double check with API credentials and also check if you are entering sandbox account details than sandbox mode should be enabled. you can also regenerate the credentials.

Comment: Account type also matters, please check you have a business account type of that sandbox account.